# PostgreSQL query within PostGIS function

Tags: postgis

I am trying to run the following PostGIS query:

```
select ST_distance_spheroid(
  ST_GeomFromText('POINT(
    (select AsText(location) from test where name="EGMC")
  )', 4326),
  ST_GeomFromText('POINT(
    (select AsText(location) from test where name="EGDY")
  )', 4326),
  'SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137,298.257223563]'
);
```

but keep getting an error:

```
ERROR:  parse error - invalid geometry
HINT:  "POINT(
(s" <-- parse error at position 9 within geometry
```

I'm happy that I know what the error means, I just don't know how to go about achieving what I want to do. I don't want to manually specify the location, it's stored in the database! I know the name of the place, so I want to get it's location by looking it up. How should I be doing this? Also, it seems a bit unnecessary to convert to a string to convert back, what else can I do?

If I can do this without having to specify variables that would be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing SQL and WKT, [which are not the same](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/24487/1872). Furthermore, you don't need to recreate geometries that already exist. Query the existing geometries instead:

```
select ST_distance_spheroid(g1.location, g2.location, 'SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137,298.257223563]')
from test g1, test g2
where g1.name = "EGMC" and g2.name = "EGDY";
```